# which design pattern is used in the code below?

Tags: design-patterns

Can someone please tell me which design pattern is used in the code below?

This code has been used in a recruitement test (live codingame test).
So i would like to have the answer in case the same code will be back.

````
        class UnixText
        {
        function write($txt){echo $txt;}
        function lf()   {echo "\n";}
    
        }
        
        class MSWindowsText
        {
        function write($txt){echo $txt;}
        function crlf()   {echo "\r\n";}
    
        }

        interface Writer
        {
        function write($txt);
        function newLine();
        }

        class UnixWriter implements Writer{
        private $target;
    
        public function __construct($unixText){$this->target=$unixText; }
        function write($txt){$this->target->write($txt);}
        function newLine(){$this->target->lf();}
        }

        class MSWindowsWriter implements Writer{
        private $target;
    
        public function __construct($winText){$this->target=$winText;   }
        function write($txt){$this->target->write($txt);}
        function newLine(){$this->target->crlf();}
        }
        //example of use
        $writer=NULL;
        if($isUnix){$writer= new UnixWriter(new UnixText());}
        else {$writer= new MSWindowsWriter(new MSWindowsText());}
        $writer->write('First Line');
        $writer->newLine();
        $writer->write('Second Line');
        ```
````

Comment: Looks like OOP to me

Comment: hi. any help? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the response in case it would be helpful for sommeone else.
The design pattern used in this case is Adapter.
Thanks